# C++, operator [], and tracking a change

Tags: c++, arrays, operators

I'm trying to build a little array-ish class, like so:

```
class dumb
{
    bool mChanged=false;
    int mData[1000];
    int& operator [](int i) {return mData[i];}
};
```

Here's my question-- is there any kind of hack or trick I could do so that if I did this:

```
dumb aDumbStuff;
aDumbStuff[5]=25;  <- now mChanged gets set to true!
```

So basically, I want my class's mChanged value to go true if I modify any content.  Any way to do this without making the array itself an array of objects that they themselves track getting changed, or by doing memcmps to see if things changed at all?

Some complex dance of assignment operators that would let my class detect "[n]=" happening?

Comment: You would need to wrap the data in another object, and overload it's assignment operator. Unless you're okay with just any time the operator [] is used, marking it as changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the flag to 'changed' inside your existing `operator[]` method, and add a second version with `const` returning an `int` (= not as a reference):

`int operator [](int i) const {return mData[i];}`

The compiler would pick the right one - modifying or not, as needed!

Comment: This would not work if you don't change the value on a non-const object, since it would always change the flag, regardless if the value was changed.

Comment: This works surprisingly well, at least for the limited uses I have for this class.

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution is to use a helper class, something like:

```
struct inner_ref {
   dumb &me;
   int i;

   inner_ref(dumb &, int);

   operator int();

   dumb &operator=(int);
};
```

The `operator[]` overload returns this object, constructing it using a reference to `*this`, and the passed-in array index. Its `operator=` overload executes the actual assignment and also sets this flag. Its `operator int()` provides the appropriate semantics when `[]` is used to access the array's value, rather than modifying it.